# enum class mapping issue when enum not found

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I have a class in kotlin which is an enum class as below

```
enum class Status {
  @SerializedName("open")
  OPEN,
  @SerializedName("close")
  CLOSE,
  UNKNOWN
}
```

I have another class called ticket using the status enum class

```
class Order(
    var id: String,
    var status: Status = Status.UNKNOWN,
}
```

When the GSON map the value received, I have an exception because the `status` field now contains a new value `in_progress`. As this state is not declared in the `Status` class, the exception happened.

How can I avoid the exception to make sure that if a new status is set in the GSON but not defined in the `Status` class, I got status `UNKNOWN`?

Any idea on how to return a default value `UNKNOWN` in my case when nothing match ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin much, but you can try writing your custom deserializer for the enum. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down this road then your problem is the enum. GSON is waiting for an enum value so if in_progress isn't a value GSON will say no.

What you can do is creating a new datatyp and wrap your enum in it, but the generell Idea for using a enum is lost.

A different approach is to get rid of the enum completely. Implementing an interface called status and implement a class for every type of Status. This is kinda a enum+. You can than send your Order with something like
Var Status : OrderStatus = In_Progress()
Var Status: OrderStatus = Unkonwn()
Later you can call something like instanceof to get the type of OrderStatus checked.

After your edit:
You must say GSON exactly what you are waiting for (see GSON Adapters) if you want the behaviour from your description you should look for an other way to communicate.